# Connecting a webcam to NXT and streaming a video

Tags: nxt, compatibility

is it possible to connect any webcam or modify it in such a way that the NXT controller will be able to stream a video to another computer? Iv'e seen there are special sensors for it, but I can't really buy one on the internet.

So is there a way to take a webcam and connect it to the NXT controller? Also, is it possible to stream videos through Bluetooth? Or do I need to somehow connect the controller to the internet?

Answer (score 1):

The only camera capable of connecting directly to the NXT is the [Vision Subsystem for NXT or EV3](http://www.mindsensors.com/index.php?module=pagemaster&PAGE_user_op=view_page&PAGE_id=78):

[image: Vision Subsystem for NXT or EV3]

With modified firmware, [it is possible to send images from the cam to the NXT to the computer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ppNCzDb7lU). But trying to stream video via this technique is impractical since each frame takes about 30 seconds to send to the computer. If you had a connection over USB, it would probably operate faster, but still not fast enough to effectively stream video.

If your goal is for the images to reach the computer, though, why does it need to pass through the NXT first? Why not use a webcam that sends the video directly to the computer? It would be much faster. There's software to support controlling NXT robots and receiving video from the webcam, such as [iCommand](http://www.lejos.org/p_technologies/nxt/icommand/icommand.php). Or alternatively, you could have one window streaming video, and have the NXT software or [BricxcC](http://bricxcc.sourceforge.net/) open in another window for controlling your robot.

Comment: This exactly. Do you really need to have the camera connect to the NXT? It is much easier to just physically attach a completely separate webcam on your creation that handles the whole streaming itself over some wireless connection (e.g. a separate Bluetooth, an existing WiFi or some proprietary protocol).

Comment: That's not the only camera you can connect. There's the Pixy camera that has similar capabilities: http://charmedlabs.com/default/pixy-for-lego-mindstorms/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use something better - Raspberry Pi. It can control motors via shield and transmit video via bluetooth. It is cheaper then mindstorms and needs only Power functions.

[Vehicle with control via bluetooth](http://privateblog.info/lego-vezdexod-s-video-i-bluetooth/)[image: Vehicle with control via bluetooth]